# Android and ios always leads to opening the Play Store (browser-deeplink)

Tags: deep-linking

I am using browser-deepling.js for deeplinking (https://github.com/hampusohlsson/browser-deeplink/) but android and ios always open into the app store even app is installed.

```
<button type="button" class="view"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-uri="myapp://example.com" onclick="openApp(this.dataset.uri)"> view</a></button>


<script>
 deeplink.setup({
    iOS: {
        appName: "App name",
        appId: "app_id",
    },
    android: {
        appId: "app id"
    }
});

    function openApp(url){
    deeplink.open(url);    
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This GitHub code that you have linked is, itself, not capable of opening apps using Universal Linking, which is a requirement for opening apps on iOS, or App Links, the equivalent Android technology.

I think you are looking for Branch's free service here (https://branch.io). Firebase also has a Branch knock-off service I believe.